# Adapting the Command Pattern to a singleton that makes multiple API connections

Tags: c#, java, oop, design-patterns

A teammate wrote a connector to a service that instantiates an API connection and proceeds to use that same connection throughout the code. It turns out that the way these connectors are created, they're actually singletons. So as soon as more than one connection is needed, we'll have a lot of trouble on our hands. I was about to just rewrite the connector, but another teammate said something about how this was a good place to use the Command pattern.

Unfortunately, the only examples I can find online are ones where the Commands in question relate to undoing things, or menus. In this context, what sort of functionality do things like Invoker, Receiver, Command, etc map onto?

```
Pattern Term    My domain
Invoker      -> Connection instance
Receiver     -> ?
Command(s)   -> GetSomeData(userInfo, creds, constraints), GetSomeOtherData(userInfo, creds, constraints), ...
User         -> Connector singleton? 
Invoker      -> Also Connector singleton?
```

I was going to just move the API Connection object into its own class, rather than being a property on the Connector singleton, and then `new` up that Connection object with the proper creds and pass it along to each GetSomeData method. Am I wrong in finding the command pattern stuff to be a little bit overkill-y?

Sorry for the somewhat disjointed question, it boils down to: what command pattern concept maps onto which of my current concerns, and what are the benefits of doing it that way?

Comment: I don't see Command pattern as applicable here, but I could be misunderstanding.  Ask your teammate how he'd use Command pattern and let us know so we can comment on that!

Answer (score 0):

To me your teammate seems to have misunderstood something.

Using Command pattern would not really help you other than creating a queue of ''task/data`` to send threw the connection. Undo is no use in that case, but you could actually serialized/saved each command with the Memento Pattern and create a log of every command sent threw the connection.

I think your partner, miss the point on which multiple connections will be concurrent if your server is able to sustain concurrent calls.

So either you partner missed something, either your server does not handle concurrency.
Command pattern will in your case only be used to create a log book and with memento store/restore command that have failed/succeeded